# Visual Studio Code Snippets From Snippet Designer All Fail To Import

Tags: visual-studio, t-sql, code-snippets

So i have created a handful of SQL snippets from some common scripts i run here.
I am using [Snippet Designer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/B08B0375-139E-41D7-AF9B-FAEE50F68392/view/Discussions) and Visual Studio 2013.

Every time i try to import them i get the message "Selected snippets are not valid".

being that some of them are fairly large I did a little bit of digging looking for invalid chars (very new to snippets so could have easily missed some). This still did not work.

So I decided, lets make a VERY simple snippet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Keywords>
        <Keyword>Why</Keyword>
        <Keyword>Does</Keyword>
        <Keyword>This</Keyword>
        <Keyword>Not</Keyword>
        <Keyword>Work</Keyword>
      </Keywords>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>SimpleSnipThantShouldNotFailAndDoes</Title>
      <Author>I am</Author>
      <Description>some thing in here</Description>
      <HelpUrl>
      </HelpUrl>
      <Shortcut>simplesnip</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="sql"><![CDATA[select *
from sometable]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

still manages to throw the error, Im hoping that one of you snippet gurus out there can point out the issue here and that may let me identify the issue for the others.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a bit late, but I will answer anyway, maybe it will be useful for others coming here.

The problem is, that you defined a Code Snippet for SQL and try to import it into Visual Studio. However, your VS does not have the ability to "write SQL".

If you change the Code Language tag to e.g. `<Code Language="CSHARP">` the snippet will import correctly and will be available in C# files.
(see [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms171418.aspx#code) for more language values)

As is see it, you can only add snippets for the language that are available in the dropdown menu in the upper left of the Code Snippet Manager (CTRL + K, CTRL + B).

If you want TSQL Code as a snippet in your C# code, simply change it, as the snippet will not be parsed against compiler rules (it will, after you inserted it).

Otherwise, your xml imports into SMSS just fine.

Comment: so looking at the list in the link you provided it show sql in the language list? is this a case sensitive issue? I use  VS to manage and write a lot of my SQL and am looking to add this as SQL snip when i am working with a .sql file thanks for the answer though def getting me closer

Comment: SQL Code Snippets are indeed supported, but not by Visual Studio, at least in 2010. You can only add snippets to languages in VS that are available in the top left corner of the Snippet Manager. Of course VS is able to open .sql files, as they are only text files, but when I open one in VS, I cannot open the snippert insert by pressing CTRL+K, CTRL+X anyway. "They key combination (CTRL+K, CTRL+X) is bound to command (Insert Snippet) which is not currently available." So either you need to add real SQL File Support to your VS or do workarounds by changing file endings. Alternative: Use SSMS